# About the property of a sequence of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> There is a sequence of polynomials $P_n(x)$ such that $P_0(x) = x^3 - 4x$ and, for $n>0$, 
>   $$P_n(x) = P_{n-1}(1+x)P_{n-1}(1-x) - 1.$$ 
>   Prove that $x^{2016}$ divides $P_{2016}(x)$.

I tried induction, but then I had to prove that $x^n \vert P_n(x)P_n(2 - x) + P_n(-x)P_n(2+x)$

Comment: What is $P_0(x)$ ?

Comment: @Peter it's like $T_0$ i.e. term 0, or in this case polynomial 0

Comment: You must share your thoughts and any attempts you have made.

Comment: Do you mean that $P_0(x)$ is ANY polynomial?

Comment: @AndiQu I mean : don't we know $P_0(x)$ ?

Comment: Did you try by induction?

Comment: @RobertZ sorry, I forgot to add P0's value

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's by induction somehow, I'll think a bit more about it...may be get the remainder theorem involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We show by induction that $x^n(x-2)(x+2)$ divides $P_n(x)$ for any even integer $n$.

For $n=0$, $P_0=x(x+2)(x-2)$ and the property holds. Let $n>0$. Note that
$$P_{n+2}(x)=(P_{n}(2+x)P_{n}(-x)-1)(P_{n}(2-x)P_{n}(x)-1)-1.$$
If $x^n(x-2)(x+2)$ divides $P_n(x)$ then, for some polynomial $Q_n(x)$,
$$P_{n}(2+x)P_{n}(-x)=(x+2)^{n+1}x^{n+1}(x-2)Q_n(x)$$
and 
$$P_{n}(2-x)P_{n}(x)=-(x+2)x^{n+1}(x-2)^{n+1}Q_n(-x).$$
Therefore, for some polynomial $R_n(x)$,
\begin{align*}
P_{n+2}(x)&=((x+2)^{n+1}x^{n+1}(x-2)Q_n(x)-1)(-(x+2)x^{n+1}(x-2)^{n+1}Q_n(-x)-1)-1\\
&=x^{n+1}(x+2)(x-2)\left(x^{n+1}R_n(x)-(x+2)^nQ_n(x)+(x-2)^nQ_n(-x)\right).
\end{align*}
Since $n$ is even, 
$$\left.\left(x^{n+1}R_n(x)-(x+2)^nQ_n(x)+(x-2)^nQ_n(-x)\right)\right|_{x=0}=0-2^nQ_n(0)+(-2)^nQ_n(0))=0$$
which implies that we have an extra factor $x$ (or, as remarked by Nick Pavlov, since $P_{n+2}$ is even, if the odd polynomial $x^{n+1}$ divides $P_{n+2}$ then $x^{n+2}$ divides it as well).

Hence $x^{n+2}(x+2)(x-2)$ divides $P_{n+2}$ and the proof of the inductive step is complete.

Comment: Couldn't you say for the last part, more simply, that if $x^{n+1}$ is a factor, and $P_{n+2}(x)$ is an even polynomial (which can be seen directly from the recursive formula for every $n > 0$, not just even ones), then it must have $x^{n+2}$ as a factor when $n$ is even?

Comment: @NickPavlov I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out!